# "The destination folder does not exist or is not writeable" error at Android Studio 3.4.2 when try to generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed new version Android studio 3.4.2.
I developed few android project in older android studio version . But now I am not able to generate signed apk in 3.4.2 version. Unable to release next update. Can any body help me. Thanks in advance for your valuable time.
[image]

Comment: Try chmod to make access if you have some extra protection software... - "not writable" indicate no permission.

Comment: Solve the problem by changing path. The spelling was wrong in path.

Answer (score 14):

changing the path of destination apk to different path. (for C :) you might be able to solve it.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on Linux, but I changed the path to a direction on my main Linux partition.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, after lots of debugging I could find a solution. it's super easy.

just make sure this two-path should be the same:

### Project folder path:

[image]

### Generate Signed Bundle or APK Destination Folder:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and it was because I'd changed my project's folder name to something different, and the APK was still trying to be built to the original folder (which of course now no longer existed). Just update the output folder name in the dialog box to match what the project's new folder name now is.

Answer (score 3):

Try and change the path of destination of your apk or reset your android studio

Answer (score 1):

Check your project File Name may be you can change your  project name,in my case i am facing same issue and try to search on google but didn't resolve then i saw my project name and it different's from designation folder where apk release.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. check the `jks` file path is correct
2. Take a look if the output path of the compiled package is correct

Answer (score 0):

One of the following points can fix this issue.

- invalidate cache and restart
- update android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My problem when generate signed APK, just changing the output.

[image: aaaaa]

Answer (score -2):

Just choose the destination path in Generate signed apk and bundle screen:-
Like mine is:-
project_destination\app\release